# VSTS : dotnet with Docker fail to publish tests

Tags: unit-testing, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, azure-devops

I try to publish my unit tests on VSTS during the continuous integration, I use docker, and at the time the Publish task is played, I still get the following error, thus the xml file resulting from the **dotnet test** command can"t be found.

```
No test result files matching **\test-results.xml were found.
```

If I run the command **docker-compose run web-tests** locally, a tests-results folder is created containing the expected test-results.xml file.

**What I am doing wrong on VSTS ?**

The code repo : [Github](https://github.com/NicolasReyDotNet/UnitTestDocker)

My folder architecture:

```
web/
├── web/
│   └── web.csproj
│   └── Dockerfile
│       
├── web.test/
│  └── web.test.csproj
│       
└── web.sln
└── docker-compose.yml
└── docker-compose.override.yml
```

Dockerfile (EDIT remove extra dotnet test command) :

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src 
COPY web.sln ./
COPY web/web.csproj web/
COPY web.test/web.test.csproj web.test/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/web
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build as test
WORKDIR /src/web.test
#RUN dotnet test

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /src/web
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "web.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    image: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web/Dockerfile
  web-tests:
    image: web-tests
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web/Dockerfile      
      target: test
    volumes: 
      - ${BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY:-./tests-results/}:/tests
```

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"
  web-tests:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"
    entrypoint:
      - dotnet
      - test
      - --logger
      - trx;LogFileName=/tests/test-results.xml
```

And my both VSTS Tasks 
[image: docker-compose run task]
[image: publish tests task]

Comment: You make release build in Dockerfile, but `dotnet test` by default would launch a debug build. Force `dotnet test` to run on a release build and you should get what you want.

Comment: It works on my locale machine (test folder and test file are created ) without changing any parameter, it would be the same on vsts no?

Comment: You are using BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY variable that the value may null, so the test result will be mapped to ./tests-results/. Try to specify the environment variable in Environment Variable input box of Docker Compose task, then use it in volumn (replace BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY to that variable)

Comment: Ok lets remove the env variable and set it hard coded : VSTS still can't find xml results files... The original idea was from [here](https://geeks.ms/etomas/2018/03/07/ejecutar-pruebas-de-tus-contenedores-en-vsts/) but it seems there is missing something. It set my code into a public repo. I'll be very glad if someone can achieve want I need (ie : publish this test result xml file into VSTS from Docker). The repo link is here : [Github](https://github.com/NicolasReyDotNet/UnitTestDocker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncheck **Run In Background** option of Docker Compose task.

[image]

Comment: it finally worked,  many thanks ! As I understood tasks where not synchronous resulting on a publish task launched before the test xml file was created right ? I've been on this problem for 5 days now, you saved my week!

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `RUN dotnet test` in the `Dockerfile` as you are running the tests using the `entrypoint` option in compose file.
If you have the `RUN dotnet test` and any test fails, the whole build will fail without generating any test result file.

If all your tests pass, then the "publish test results" tasks should succeed (but note that you run the tests twice).

Did you tried with a successful test suite?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Okay I removed the dotnet test command from Dockerfile. The task is now running only once (thanks for that), but stil get the same problem : the xml file can't be found. Moreover before (with dotnet test command) I was able to see the results (passing or not) where now this outpur doesn't appear anymore : are the tests played then ?

Comment: The problem was about the docker compose task that was running in background. Anyway your whole article is amazing, and I suggest you t publish it in a wiki (maybe in english to be more visible ?)

Comment: Sorry guys but I missed where you actually set the BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY environment variable and what value are you using for your code to work?